# C# FTP upload problems

Tags: c#, ftp

im working on a program for my school. i am just about done, i only needed to upload my file to an FTP. when i finished the code, and tested it, the application was put in break mode. when i removed the FTP code, it still would function.
do any of you have a clue whats wrong? im using core.NET C#
here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace School_0._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            comboBox2.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            comboBox3.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Weet je het zeker?", "Lesbord 1.0", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verstuurd");
                //hier de verstuur code
                string path = @"E:\\test.txt";
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string selectedValue2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string selectedValue1 = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

                File.WriteAllText(path, selectedValue + " " + selectedValue2 + " " + selectedValue1);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Weet je zeker dat je het programma af wil sluiten?", "Lesbord 1.0", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E\printscreen.jpeg");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the FTP code:

```
private static void Upload(string ftpServer, string userName, string password, string filename)
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName,password);
        client.UploadFile(ftpServer+"/"+newFileInfo(filename).Name,"STOR",filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to add it, oops! my mistake. will update it now

Comment: What is "break mode"? Explain the problem. Catch the exception. Debug the application. You're missing a lot of crucial steps before we can meaningfully help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are done with your `File.WriteAllText`, just implement the code you find in [this tuturial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp) in your `Upload` method and call it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Weet je het zeker?", "Lesbord 1.0", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Verstuurd");
        //hier de verstuur code
        string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selectedValue2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selectedValue1 = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

        File.WriteAllText(@"E:\test.txt", selectedValue + " " + selectedValue2 + " " + selectedValue1);

        Upload("ftp://www.myserver.com/", "myuser", "mypass", @"E:\test.txt");
    }
}
```

I would also implement a little `try... catch` block in order to handle potential exceptions when writing or uploading the file, since the example I linked to you doesn't implement any. For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Weet je het zeker?", "Lesbord 1.0", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Verstuurd");
        //hier de verstuur code
        string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selectedValue2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selectedValue1 = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

        try {
            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\test.txt", selectedValue + " " + selectedValue2 + " " + selectedValue1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during file writing!");
            return;
        }

        try {
            Upload("ftp://www.myserver.com/", "myuser", "mypass", @"E:\test.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during file upload!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation:

```
    private static void Upload(string ftpServer, string userName, string 
password, string filename)
    {  
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer);  
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);  

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.  
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename);  
        byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());  
        sourceStream.Close();  
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;  

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();  
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);  
        requestStream.Close();  

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  
        response.Close();  
    }
```

Comment: and where do i add the location? in the upload command or in the private static void?

Comment: This is as you prefer. You can either define all your parameters (ftp user, ftp pass, ftp address, file path) in private static strings within your form class, or you can just write them inline. If I was given the choice, I would go for the former.

Comment: it works but it says "the application is in break mode"

Comment: it stalls on the string     path = @"E\\text.txt" did I make an syntax error?

Comment: Tep, my mistake I didn't fix it: @"E:\test.txt".

Comment: it still goes into break mode?

Comment: This doesn't help me at all.

Comment: what info do you need? EDIT: i just found out it is probably something with the File.writeall command.

Answer (score 0):

You are just writing in .txt file ...
Try  File.Save() function after
File. Writealltext()

Comment: File.Save doesnt get accepted? (im a bit of a noobie when it comes to this stuff)